# Deploy to Bluemix button will not reuse project names

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I have set up the 'Deploy to Bluemix' button in my project here: https://hub.jazz.net/project/dschultz_mo/EmployeeDirectory-STARTER/overview.  It works great as long as I use a new project name each time.  If I use a project name that I have used in the past - even if that project has been deleted days ago - I get the message that the project name is in use (EmployeeDirectory-DWS2).

UPDATE: After trying a few more times, it seems to only be the project name EmployeeDirectory-DWS2 that it won't allow me to use.  I have checked multiple times but that project name is not used in jazz.hub projects nor bluemix.net applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check to see there is not an app with the name of EmployeeDirectory-DWS2.  To do this login to the Bluemix Console then click on dashboard and look through your orgs and spaces to ensure that app does not exist.

Also, you can do this with the Cloud Foundry CLI.  Run the following against all your orgs and spaces.

`cf apps`

Run the following to check the used routes.

`cf routes`

You can then delete the routes with the following.

`cf delete-route mybluemix.net -n HOSTNAME -f`

Comment: Yeah, I already have several times.  There isn't one - at least not visible in the UI.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is ultimately an authentication issue.  I can log in through the UI, but when I use the same creds, they are rejected using cf login.

Comment: As of this morning, I am told "The name is already used by another app." For the following app names: EmployeeDirectoryDWS, EmployeeDirectory-DWS, EmployeeDirectory-DWS2.  These are all app names I have used over the last several days, but all of which have since been deleted from DevOps Services and Bluemix.

Comment: @DSchultz_mo Updated my answer on how to delete routes.

Comment: Interesting... I had seven orphaned routes not associated to apps.  Deleting them seems to have cleared up the issues with the "Deploy to Bluemix" button.  Thanks.